# Highlight selected tableViewCell to match with UITextfield.text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview with values that could be the same.

When selecting the cell, the textfield value will be populated with the selected cell.

I want to only highlight the row that was selected rather than highlight all the values that are the same as the textfield.

My approach currently:

where `data` is an array of possible values

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
    reuseIdentifier:@"identifierCell"];
}

NSString *value = ([self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
NSString *selectedValue = textField.text;

if ([value floatValue] == [selectedValue floatValue]) {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:220.0/255.0 green:220.0/255.0 blue:220.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
else {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

Side note: I have a couple of these drop down fields that can change the textfield text depending on which row was selected. (i.e. if row 1 was selected in the other dropdown, then `1.391` would be populated in the textfield text.

Not sure how relevant that will be.

How would I check only the row that was selected and populate the textfield per the image below?

[image]

**Update**: Thanks to @k06a using indexPath is a step forward, however the problem now arises where when if row A is selected, the indexPath for B should not change. I was thinking of setting 2 different indexPath variables and on `didSelectRowAt` only set those for the methods I'm calling to change the other respective values

[image]

Comment: You can achieve multiple cells selection by using `UITableView`s `allowsMultipleSelection` property.

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate all cells within a loop to select and deselect rows based on `selectedValue` and `value` equality. This loop will deselect previous row, and select a new one. And not forget to setup initial state after dequeing reusable cell. All cells can be fetched with: `self.tableView.visibleCells`

Or you can just deselect previous cell by remembering its indexPath. And select a new one and remember its indexPath. This is the most effective variant.

Or you can just call `[self.tableView reloadData]` when wanna change selection. This will be less effective, but shorter and easier to implement.

**UPDATE:**

Just use different condition of cell selection not basing on value but basing on indexPath. And remind me why do you need manual selection of cell? I mean manual setting `backgroundColor` and `textColor` can be automatic by `[UITableViewCell setSelected:]` selection.

Comment: Could you show please show an example? I am not quite following the first two methods.

Comment: I do manual setting of cell because I have 3 of those textfield boxes. Each of them populate different values for tableview when selected. When row is tapped, all values change to the row that was tapped. I tried the `setSelected` method you showed but to no success.

Comment: The `indexPath` is a step forward however, I forgot to mention the other requirement. updated above

Answer (score 1):

My solution thanks to @k06a

```
NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPathA;
NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPathB;
```

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` I pass in the indexPath to the method that will set these values:

```
[self setOtherFieldsWithIndexPath:indexPath];
```

and in `setOtherFieldsWithIndexPath` method

```
if (rowA) { selectedIndexPathA = indexPath; }
else if (rowB) { selectedIndexPathB = indexPath; }
else {...}
```

then finally in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
if (selectedIndexPathA.row == indexPath.row) {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:220.0/255.0 green:220.0/255.0 blue:220.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
else if (selectedIndexPathB.row == indexPath.row) {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:220.0/255.0 green:220.0/255.0 blue:220.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
else {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

Not sure if this is the best solution but, it currently works the way I want it to work.